# Does hermeneutics refer to Hebrew text after,translation , or is exegesis and hermenutics always about original text of original language?

Tags: hebrew-bible, hermeneutical-approaches, torah, word-choice, bible-in-basic-english

I am confused! Biblical text seems to be gloss or whitewash,of original Tora and Tanach text, in some cases! To do a proper study of the scripture at hand,should one convert the text of any bible first, to its original language, in order to get an accurate rendering of the original wording used by the Tora and Tanach author, whom composed the ancient text!

Comment: The original language must be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about what the term refers to in the title of this site, [this may be helpful](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/what-precisely-is-biblical-hermeneutics). It is from @curiousdannii, one of the moderators here:

> The subject of this site is the discipline of Biblical Studies. This
> is broader than just pure hermeneutics (often equated with exegesis,
> though sometimes subtly distinguished from it), and includes... textual criticism, as well as source criticism, form criticism,
> and so on. Many Stack Exchange sites have names which don't perfectly
> match their subject matters, but it's not like ours is a misleading
> name, as probably about 90% of questions are about exegesis proper.

Given this understanding, in this forum one does not need to deal with the text in its original language, although such knowledge is a very useful too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a scholarly answer! (This might be because I am strictly a layman, trying to study scholarly material, as best I can, without the skill set needed to properly do this) My limited answer will be this one despite it not being a good one!

I feel to properly do a Bible Study, one will have to always get back to the original penmanship of the original author (or authors) of any scripture, or narrative examined today, in a faraway land and culture! (This may be hermeneutics and exegesis, in my Layman's terminology) If one does nothing, so to speak, and just accepts the gloss presented as reality in most Biblical Studies as this. Study is referred to by most church groups, one will not have an accurate knowledge about the biblical material one seeks to examine! Until a thorough grammatical, historical review of the ancient text studied is completed, only speculation about the ancient writing can be had! One has to first find out somehow what Hebrew, or Aramaic words the original author penned to parchment or papyrus by lamp light, many years ago!

Comment: Since you have not posted a profile of yourself anyone that may try to help you is at a loss. This site is worldwide and what native language or other languages you may speak could influence the answers you receive. You seem to have a negative opinion of the Bible and the accuracy of the scriptures. If that is the case, I suggest an original  King James Bible and a Strong's Concordance. With the concordance you can look up virtually every word in the Bible and where it appears and then using the Hebrew and Greek dictionaries included, see the original words in the original languages

Comment: You need to know the Strong's Concordance is built to work in conjunction with a King James Bible. There are more than one texts that are referred to as original that are used to translate the various modern translations. Therefore it becomes a matter of faith to believe that God inspired the writing of the original manuscripts as well as protected the subsequent translation. Hermeneutics is a word that is not even in my 40 year old Webster's New World Dictionary. You can Google it and exegesis but it still may be an opinion of this site exactly how to interpret and draw out the meaning .

Comment: I have always thought, and still do, the closer we one can retrieve what was penned, to parchment or similar, by lamplight, with stylus and ink, many centuries ago, the closer we might get to an understanding of what and why the author wrote as he did! Any faith, one might have that all theologians or others will always adhere to this is at best, wishful thinking! I only want faith, in truth claims that have a data set pointing to more possibility for reality than against it! I feel GOD, as in our modern construct and terminology, is forced back onto an ancient narrative about a Hebrew deity!

Comment: Spoken like a philosopher. As you get to my age and see prayers answered and miracles that have no explanation, but yet they were, you begin to learn to appreciate the word. That said, there are always some mysteries in the Word that can be analized and hope to be understood. I try to make it fun.